# cast CFTypeRef to Boolean in objective c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, casting, objective-c++, core-foundation

I want to convert an objective c code to objective cpp and use it in my application. Given the following code:

```
        CFTypeRef dynamicValue = (__bridge CFTypeRef)([[NSBundle bundleWithPath:aStr] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFPlugInDynamicRegistration"]);

        BOOL removeFlag = NO;

        if(dynamicValue == nil)
        {
            removeFlag = NO;
        }
        else if( CFGetTypeID(dynamicValue) == CFBooleanGetTypeID()  )
        {
            removeFlag = CFBooleanGetValue(dynamicValue);
        }
        else if( CFGetTypeID(dynamicValue) == CFStringGetTypeID()  )
        {
            removeFlag = ( [[(__bridge NSString*)dynamicValue lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"yes"] ? YES:NO);
        }

        if( removeFlag )
        {       
            [unloadedArray addObject:aStr];
            [sortedArray removeObjectAtIndex:hoge];
        }
```

I get an error when changing the file name from file.m to file.mm and  building: "no matching function for call to 'CFBooleanGetValue'"

I tried to `#include <CoreFoundation/CFNumber.h>` but I get the same error (I guess it's an `ifdef` issue).

Do you know any way I can cast without the missing function? Should I try to use the same function anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C++ doesn't have automatic framework linking.
You need `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` and manually link CoreFoundation framework.

Comment: That is not what I experienced. I put OP's code into a main.mm file. After adding the static cast for the CFBooleanGetValue argument, the code compiled and linked without problems. No manual linking necessary.

Comment: @MartinR, Ah, right! I think all apps got linked implicit  with CoreFoundation anyway. And Foundation.h already includes CoreFoundation.h.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this CFNumberGetTypeID()

```
 NSString *aStr = @"";

    CFTypeRef dynamicValue = (__bridge CFTypeRef)([[NSBundle bundleWithPath:aStr] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFPlugInDynamicRegistration"]);

    BOOL removeFlag = NO;

    if(dynamicValue == nil)
    {
        removeFlag = NO;
    }
    else if( CFGetTypeID(dynamicValue) == CFNumberGetTypeID()  )
    {
        removeFlag = [(__bridge NSNumber *)dynamicValue boolValue];
    }
    else if( CFGetTypeID(dynamicValue) == CFStringGetTypeID()  )
    {
        removeFlag = ( [[(__bridge NSString*)dynamicValue lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"yes"] ? YES:NO);
    }

    if( removeFlag )
    {
        [unloadedArray addObject:aStr];
        [sortedArray removeObjectAtIndex:hoge];
    }
```

Comment: What about `CFGetTypeID(dynamicValue) == CFBooleanGetTypeID()`, your example handles only `CFNumberGetTypeID` and `CFStringGetTypeID`, while my problem occurs when it's `CFBooleanGetTypeID`

Comment: Bool is number 0,1

Answer (score 0):

In C++ a conversion from a `void *`  (here: `CFTypeRef`) to a 
pointer of a different type (here: `CFBooleanRef` aka `__CFBoolean *`) requires an explicit
cast. So this would solve the issue:

```
removeFlag = CFBooleanGetValue(static_cast<CFBooleanRef>(dynamicValue));
```

But actually I would forget about the `CF` types and bridging, and change the code to

```
id dynamicValue = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"path"] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFPlugInDynamicRegistration"];
BOOL removeFlag = NO;
if ([dynamicValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    removeFlag = ((NSNumber *)dynamicValue).boolValue;
} else if ([dynamicValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    removeFlag = [((NSString *)dynamicValue).lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"yes"];
}
```

This compiles in Objective-C and Objective-C++.

Comment: Your first example won't compile in objective c++, because of the CFBooleanGetValue - that's the root of my problem...
About the second one - is it safe to assume that the king is either `NSNumber ` or `NSString `? it means that Boolean is kind of `NSNumber`?

Comment: @benams: Actually I tried my first example in an .mm file and it compiled without problems. – If the value is something else then none of the if-blocks will be executed, and the boolean variable remains `NO`. That is the same behaviour as in your code.

Comment: @benams: And yes, a boolean in a property list is returned as an instance of `NSNumber`